# How to open some fragment from bottom nav bar fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have bottom nav bar with 3 fragments defined in the Main activity. In one of the fragments I want to open some fragment by clicking item in recycler view under calendar view [(screen 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsVfT.jpg). When i click on it a new fragment opens with bottom nav bar [(screen 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSEgV.jpg). How to open this new fragment without bottom nav bar displaying architecturally correct?

```
class ScheduleFragment : Fragment(), EventCardAdapter.OnEventClickListener{

    private lateinit var calendarView: CalendarView
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: EventCardAdapter
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, container, false)

        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        viewAdapter = EventCardAdapter(events, this)

      recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view)

      return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_view)
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "$dayOfMonth/$month/$year",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }

    recyclerView.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = viewManager
        adapter = viewAdapter
    }


}

    // moving to fragment by clicking item in recycler
    override fun onEventClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_scheduleFragment_to_attendanceEntryFragment)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

on the hosted activity implement on destination changed listener callback then when destination id equal to one of the fragments u want to show nav bar on it set nav bar visibilty to visible else set it to gone

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{}
```